# Trying to parse excel string

Tags: excel

I am trying to parse a string from teamspeak. I am new to the functions of excel. I have accomplished this with php but I am driving myself nuts excel. This is the string I am trying to parse:

```
[URL=client://4792/noEto+VRGdhvT9/iV375Ck1ZIfo=~Rizz]Rizz[/URL]
```

This is what I have accomplished so far:

```
=TRIM(MID(B22, 15, FIND("=",B22,12) - FIND("//",B22)))
```

which returns

```
4792/noEto+VRGdhvT9/iV375Ck1ZIfo=~
```

I am trying to get it to return:

```
noEto+VRGdhvT9/iV375Ck1ZIfo=
```

Any suggestions? I am looked of splitting of strings and the phrasing is just really confusing. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Is anything in the string constant? For example, do they always begin with "URL=client://4792/", or can the beginning of the url be different each time?

Answer (score 0):

Paste the URL in A3, then this formula in B3. You can adjust the cell references as needed. It's a lot of nested functions, but it works.

```
=left(right(A3, len(A3)-find("/",A3,find("//",A3,1)+2)),find("=",right(A3, len(A3)-find("/",A3,find("//",A3,1)+2)),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a user-defined function in VBA:

```
Function RegexExtract(myRange As Range) As String
'VBA Editor, menu Tools - References, add reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Dim regex As New RegExp, allMatches As MatchCollection

With regex
    .Global = True
    .pattern = "\d+/(.+=)"
End With

Set allMatches = regex.Execute(myRange.Value)

With allMatches
    If .Count = 1 Then
        RegexExtract = .Item(0).SubMatches(0)
    Else
        RegexExtract = "N/A"
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Then use it as formula:

```
=RegexExtract(A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to parse a string

For that:

```
=MID(A1,20,28)
```

works.

Now if you have *more than one* string maybe the others are not of an identical pattern, so the above might not work for *them*. But in that case if to help you we'd need to know something about the shape of the *others* wouldn't we.